# Switching between Full/Plain HTML view and setting default view

Tags: php

I am developing a website that has a plain HTML version for older browsers (I know this is not a good practice, but my employers insisted).

I put a link on the footer of all pages to switch between the views. Then I use a session variable to store whether the user is in the Full Site mode or the Plain Site mode.

However, this session variable does not get destroyed when a user quit the website. Since I want the site to show the Full Site version by default, this is a problem. I don't want the Plain Site mode to be "remembered". But it is not possible to do a destroy_session() on page exit without javascript, and it would be inefficient.

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: When a user switched to Plain-Mode there was probably a reason for this. Why annoy him with the fancy type when he comes back?

Comment: i know, but while I'm trying to convince my employer to change his mind, I need to work it out anyways in case he insists to make it work that way